# Piecewise linear approximations of Convex function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

How to prove the following:
If $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a convex function then there exists sequence of piecewise linear convex functions $\{f_n\}$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f.$

Comment: This gives you $f_n\ge f$ everywhere, with equality at points in $X_n$, not $f_n\le f$.  Chords of (say) the parabola lie _above_ the parabola, not below.

Comment: Oh!! It was a typo.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No : "enumeration of rational numbers" without precising how is done this enumeration will lead you nowhere.

I suggest you to take a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ which is the set of values defined for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ by

$$x_{k,n}:=\frac{k}{2^n}.$$

(the so-called "dyadic numbers").

Then define $f_n$ as the continuous piecewise linear coinciding with $f$ with breakpoints $x_{k,n},f(x_{k,n})$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

In this way, for any $n$ $f_{n+1}$ appears as a "refinement' of $f_n$, with convergence to $f$ that isn't difficult to establish.

Comment: How to do this approximation when the domain is $\mathbb{R}^N$? Is replacing $k$ by $k \in \mathbb{Z}^N$ enough? My confusion arises  from the fact that in $N$ dimensions, the piecewise linear segments are hyperplanes, so their intersections are not points but flats (of lower dimension). So does this hinder the above approximation process in any way? I'm not able to visualize if it does. Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: @canine360 How can this issue be considered for higher dimensions ? For $N=2$, i.e., functions $\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ it is known how to do define triangulations in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and how to refine them. If $N=3$, it would be tetrahedrizations... etc. But considering $\mathbb{Z}^N$ doesn't look me pertinent

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Is it true that a convex function $f: \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can be arbitrarily closely approximated by piecewise linear functions of the form $\max \{a^T_1x+b_1,\cdots,a^T_kx+b_k\}$  where $x,a_i,b_i \in \mathbb{R^N}\;\forall\;i$? I do not know what is triangulation and tetrahedrization. :( Thanks again.

Comment: About triangularization (in particular Delaunay triangularization) see for example this (technical) document https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.09701.pdf figure 12 aiming at convexity.

Comment: OK This was definitely helpful, to the extent that I could understand. But why can't we just select a set of points $(x_1,\cdots,x_k)$ in the domain, draw the "tangent" (a hyperplane) to the convex function at each point $(x_i,f(x_i))$ with gradient = gradient of $f$ at that point and take the maximum of these hyperplanes, to create a pcwise linear appximation of $f$?

Comment: @canine360 Yes, you can do that with gradient = vector of partial derivatives used as the normal vector to the hyperplane at that point. You will have like this an upper bound. But, afterwards, the main difficulty is to find the intersections of the hyperplanes, in particular which one goes with which one...

Comment: Right... Exactly, that was my confusion. But it's good to know that any convex function $f:\mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can be approximated as the max of linear functions like this. Thank you so much.